# Finding the norm of g

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider polynomials $f,g \in P^5(-1,1)$ satisfying $||f|| = \sqrt{6}$, $||f+g||= 4$ and $||f-g||=2$. Where the norm is the $L^2$ norm.

What is $||g||$?

Originally I though to use the triangle inequality on $||f-g||=2$ to get that $||f||= \sqrt{6} \leq ||g||+2$ but I'm unsure that this is the right way to go. I don't think we can use the triangle equality on $||f+g||$, we can but I'm unsure that it will help here. What can I do to find $||g||$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int f^{2}=6, \int (f+g)^{2}=16$ and $\int (f-g)^{2}=4$. Adding the second and the third we get $2(\int f^{2}+\int g^{2})=20$. Combined with the first we get $\int g^{2}=4$ so $\|g\|=2$.